# Repeating expo local notification with dynamic/changing content data

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-notifications

I am having troubles setting up a weekly repeating local notification with dynamic/changing content data (with expo-notifications).

Although I can create a scheduled notification for a specific day that repeats, but in my case with the "disadvantage" that the content data is static, since I would like to display a different/random quote (that I have in a locally stored json) each week.

Is there any way to update the content data before the notification is executed, as I have not found a suitable solution in the documentation?

Maybe a callback function would be useful, which would run before the notification is executed regardless of whether it's in the background or foreground to change the content data?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Or end up going a different route maybe?